# Object #<HTMLDivElement> has no method 'data'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, icalendar

I am using [this suggestion](http://dev.af83.com/2008/03/04/publishing-icalendar-events-with-ruby-on-rails.html) for how to export ics files from rails.

The problem is with this implementation it just refreshes the page and is not receiving and hence not recognizing the ics format header.